# How to see history of artifacts in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I can see the last successful build artifact in jenkins once I open the job page.

[artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUcj9.png)

How, to get previous build artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Archive Artifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) ([Archive step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBNBX.png)) is enabled, as it notes in the picture, when you are on the main <job> page, you see the link to "Last Successful Artifacts":

[image: Last Successful Artifacts]

But if you click on any entry in the build history:

[image: Build History]

You should see the artifacts for *THAT* build:
[image: Individual build]

You should also be aware of the following [Jenkins System Properties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/):

> **`hudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.listCutoff`**
> Since: 1.33   Default:        16
> Description:  More artifacts than this will use tree view or simple link rather than listing out artifacts
>
> **`hudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.treeCutoff`**
> Since: 1.33   Default:        40
> Description:  More artifacts than this will show a simple link to directory browser rather than showing artifacts in tree view
>
> **`hudson.security.ArtifactsPermission`**
> Since: 1.374  Default:        false
> Description:  The Artifacts permission allows to control access to artifacts; When this property is unset or set to false, access to
> artifacts is not controlled

You'll also want to review these S/O posts regarding [Cleaning up old artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63645491/598141) and Cleanup [Jenkins home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475906/598141) as it's quite easy to blow up your disk usage.

NOTE: Jenkins System Property, [`jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir), lets you relocate the builds (logs and artifacts) to outside the <JENKINS_HOME>, which helps.